# C# Generics How Can I get the type passed as an argument for a generic method with no object type as a parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection

I need a method to find the original type of an argument called for a generic method like this:

```
public GetGenericArgumentName<T>() where T : IFoo
{
        StackFrame fr = new StackFrame(0, true);
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(fr);
        var ga = fr.GetMethod().GetGenericArguments();

        foreach (var item in ga)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
}
```

But I couldn't get the original type at the caller.

Let's say, I have to derived classes from IFoo

```
public class Foo : IFoo {}
public class Foo2 : IFoo {}
```

If I call them with the following methods I expect these results:

```
/* 1 */ GetGenericArgumentName<Foo>()
/* 2 */ GetGenericArgumentName<Foo2>()
```

For the first one, I expected Foo as result, and for the second Foo2.
What am I missing?

Comment: Your code produces your expected output for me. What output are you seeing?

Comment: Looks like XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It shows me T as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use stack traces at all there - just use `typeof(T)`:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
```

That will print `Foo` for the first call and `Foo2` for the second call.

This is simpler, more reliably and more efficient than going up the stack.

Comment: Simple and perfect. Sometimes the answer is so easy and you cannot see it. Thanks Daisy.